# Regex search for a space followed by a character

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = 'The quick brown fox @ ';
var str = str.split(/\s/);
var str = str.join('_');
```

The result of this operation is "The_quick_brown_fox_@_", How can I only split if the space is followed by a character and this character is not a "@"?

Comment: I.e. output shoud be `The_quick_brown_fox @_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookahead:

```
str.split(/\s(?=\w)/);
```

Yields

```
["The", "quick", "brown", "fox @ "]
```

Joins into: "The_quick_brown_fox @ "

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = str.split(/\s(?!@)/);
```

Comment: The result now is "the_quick_brown_fox_@ ", the space at the end was remove successfully, however I'd like to remove the space before the @ as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp

```
/\s[^@A-Za-z]/
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?!@)(?=[^$])`

space

`(?!@)`     next symbol not @

`(?=[^$])`  ignoring last lone spase

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this without using Regex

```
var str = 'The quick brown fox @ ';
var n=str.replace(/ /g,"_");
```

Comment: Without regexp?! What is `/ /g` if it isn't a regexp?